# require password to share/ send email in excel 365

Tags: excel, email, passwords

I have a macro that requires a Password before the user can save.
I am looking to require one before the user can email using the share button to email.

here is my code for the save password macro

```
Private Sub Workbook_Beforesend(ByVal SendmailUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
'This macro disables the "Save As" Feature in Excel

'This means that a user will not be able to save this
'workbook(file) under a different name or in a different location
'
'This MUST be placed in "ThisWorkbook" and NOT in a Module.
'


    Const strPassword = "PASSWORD" ' the password to unlock Save As
If InputBox("Enter the password to display the Save As dialog, or click Cancel") <> strPassword Then
    MsgBox "You can't save this workbook!" & vbNewLine _
    & "To save this work book use the 'Click to Submit' button" & vbNewLine _
    & "this will save for you!"
    Cancel = True
       
    End If
End Sub
```